# I'm trying to display a number variable on screen after $

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I am trying to display a number. The number is in a variable because it can change. I'm trying to make something that displays how much money you have and I also wanna add "$" in front of the number. Here is what I have tried:

HTML:

```
<p id="money"> $ </p>
```

JS:

```
var money = 0;
document.getElementById('money').innerHTML = money;
```

Answer (score 3):

You're close, but if you're going to do this using JS then you should set it all inside the JS using a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). It will look a little funky because you are first using the `$` symbol as an actual string `'$'`, then you invoke the template literal using the `${}` syntax like this:

```js
var money = 0;
document.getElementById('money').innerHTML = `$${money}`;
```

```html
<p id="money"></p>
```

Comment: It is finally displaying something on my page, but instead of $0 I am getting ${money}

Comment: @WeatherlyGamer make sure you're using the ` symbol (above your tab key) and not a single quote ' - or just copy the lines I posted exactly and it should work unless you're using a browser that does not support template literals, in which case it would be `document.getElementById('money').innerHTML = '$' + money`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use append with jQuery if it only happens once:

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  var money = 0;
  $("#money").append(money);
});
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="money">$</p
```